# Filezilla: How to refresh a FTP folder automatically

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I'm using Filezilla to check if new files arrived in different folder on a FTP. But I always have to do a refresh of the folder manually with <kbd>F5</kbd>.

When I click on a folder that I already clicked before, the refresh is not done.

**How can I enable Filezilla to always update(refresh) a folder when I click it?**

Comment: What OS?  Also are you just thinking like on a specific duration like every 2 seconds?

Comment: I'm on Windows 8. It does not need to be a automatic polling all x seconds, just when I click the folder manually, it should reload the content again - but it does not.

Comment: I'm searching for an opposite wish, a caching version of Filezilla. What version you were using?

Comment: @machineaddict I'm using the most recent version. Please create a new question and ask for a caching FTP client...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With FileZilla 3, this isn't possible. [Ticket #8111](http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/8111) is an open feature request that asks for an option to disable the caching of the directory listing.

You have two options:

- Install [FileZilla 2.2.32](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/filezilla-2-2-32).

  Disabling the directory cache is straightforward in FileZilla 2:

  [image: screenshot]
- If downgrading is not an option, you can download, modify and compile the source code.

  The modification is easy. The file *src/engine/directorycache.h* of the FileZilla 3.5.3 source code contains the following:

  ```
  /*
  This class is the directory cache used to store retrieved directory listings
  for further use.
  Directory get either purged from the cache if the maximum cache time exceeds,
  or on possible data inconsistencies.
  [...]
  */

  const int CACHE_TIMEOUT = 1800; // In seconds
  ```

  As you can see, the default timeout is 1800 seconds (30 minutes). Setting the timeout to zero should disable the directory cache.

  Compiling is a lot more difficult. The official tutorial [Compiling FileZilla 3 under Windows](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Compiling_FileZilla_3_under_Windows) explains how.

Comment: 3 years old and this still hasn't been done?

Comment: now 5 years... SMH

Comment: 6 years and counting

Comment: I am using 3.42.1 in May 2019 which is the latest version and I still see the directory cache issue for remote files, pathetic service provider

Comment: ***8** years!*   (@Hansiemithun - but I'm sure there's non-free alternatives if this minor inconvenience is unbearable) ;)

Comment: PUSHING 10 YEARS TO CHANGE THAT ONE LINE!!!@#!@#

Comment: Just to keep the tradition alive: it'll be 12 full years in November. It's not realistic to think it's ever going to come, is it?