# How to turn off directory caching on Filezilla running on a Mac

Tags: macos, filezilla

How would you do this on Mac?

Effectively same question [as this one](https://superuser.com/questions/506580/filezilla-how-to-refresh-a-ftp-folder-automatically/581134)

But that answer only addresses Windows.

Would have followed up there, but I wasn’t allowed to comment there  and this isn’t an answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know about this is actually in the answer to the question you have pointed to yourself:
[Filezilla: How to refresh a FTP folder automatically](https://superuser.com/q/506580/213663).

The last missing piece are instructions for [Compiling FileZilla 3 under macOS](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Compiling_FileZilla_3_under_macOS).